Understanding intuition of the Two child problem
Inspired by this twitter thread, posting this question:

I have two children, (at least) one of whom is a boy born on a Tuesday

what is the probability that both children are boys?


Via Joel Grus, here is a proposed answer:

196 possibilities total (equal chance for each (sex, day) 27 of those
at least one Tuesday boy (13 younger Tuesday boy, older not; 13 older
Tuesday boy, younger not, 1 both) 13 of those both boys (6, 6, 1) so
13 / 27

This seems right. But also, confusing. It makes it seem like we could condition on anything arbitrarily that we know to be true (the babies were born in the Milk Way galaxy, for example; or the babies' parents speak English), and somehow use this to shift the probabilities of the posterior. Can someone take me from the existential fraught this causes?

As very often in these cases, a key point is how you define the sampling space. There are other possible 'answers' depending on which assumptions you make there. See for example this random blog post I found on it; "the answer depends on how specifically the information you are given identifies a particular child".

The solution founders at the outset by even assigning chances to sex and days: those are huge assumptions that are not justified by the information.  Depending on your statistical approach you would either deny that such chances exist or you would insist that they are subjective.  Even supposing these probability assumptions are valid, the attempted solution also misses the point that information ("born on a Tuesday") that is irrelevant to the event in the question ("both children are boys") can and ought to be ignored.

You say "* It makes it seem like we could condition on anything arbitrarily that we know to be true (the babies were born in the Milk Way galaxy, for example)*". This is in fact correct; you can condition on any condition you choose. In some cases, like for the Tuesday child, it changes the sample space (because boys could be born on days other than Tuesday). And in other cases, like your example, it does not change the sample space (because no boy can be born outside the Milky Way -at least not yet...).

@jginestet What is your point exactly?

@Estimatetheestimators, the point is that you can condition on pretty much anything. In this Tuesday child problem, while the fact that the boy is born on a Tuesday seems irrelevant, and should not change the probability, it is not irrelevant and indeed changes the probability (because it eliminates from the sample space 6/7 of the BG and GB possibilities). However, being born in the Milky Way does not change the sample space (there are no boys from other galaxies to eliminate...).  You seemed confused about the apparent irrelevance of the Tuesday condition.  The point is that it is relevant.

It's an interesting hypothesis.. but not really a good summary of what I understand or very helpful. Thanks though!


It makes it seem like we could condition on anything arbitrarily that we know to me true (the babies were born in the Milk Way galaxy, for example), and somehow use this to shift the probabilities of the posterior.

The problem with the approach is that it applies a Bayesian technique where it possibly shouldn't. Bayesian statistics is used when we make an observation from a probability distribution and when we have a prior. The knowledge 'born on a Tuesday' is not clearly such observation.
The important distinction is how we decide to make the statement about Tuesday (and similarly the boy/girl).

We sample a family with two kids, we provide either the following two statements

$X=1$ if there are one or more a boys born on tuesday
$X=0$ if there is no boys born on tuesday


We sample a family with two kids, we provide either the following two statements

$X=1$ if there are one or more boys.
And we give the day that one of the boys is born (the oldest or youngest, which we decide with a coin flip)

$X=0$ if there are no boys




In the second case, the 1st observation makes that there is 1/3 probabability for two boys. The day doesn't add any information.
In the first case the additional observation about Tuesday increases the probability for two boys compared to the second case and we get the $13/27 > 9/27$. This is because two boys make it more likely to make the observation about the specific Tuesday, so the posterior for two boys is increased.
This computation only works when it was decided beforehand whether or not the conditioning on the Tuesday was made. If we just provide the birthday of the oldest or youngest, then it wasn't conditioning.
The same is true for the statement about one of the kids being a boy, if that statement is not decided beforehand, and instead if it is the gender of a random kid.

We sample a family with two kids, pick one of those kids randomly (with equal probabability) and provide either the following two statements

$X=1$ if the randomly picked kid is a boy.

$X=0$ if the randomly picked kid is not a boy.





For 0, 1 and 2 boys the likelihood for the first case are
$$
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 0) = 0 \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 1) = \frac{1}{7} \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 2) = \frac{13}{49} 
$$
for the second case
$$
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 0) = 0 \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 1) = 1 \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 2) = 1 
$$
for the third case
$$
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 0) = 0 \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 1) = 0.5 \\
P(X=1|\text{boys} = 2) = 1 
$$
So that leads to different posterior odds:

$\frac{P(\text{boys} = 2|X=1)}{P(\text{boys} = 1|X=1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{13}{49}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{7}} = \frac{13}{14}$

$\frac{P(\text{boys} = 2|X=1)}{P(\text{boys} = 1|X=1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{4} \cdot 1}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{P(\text{boys} = 2|X=1)}{P(\text{boys} = 1|X=1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{1}$




We provide a true statement of the form "One is a  who was born on a ." There are 196 possible family combinations. And while there are 27 where "at least one is a boy who was born on a Tuesday" is true, in 26 of them there is an different, but equally-valid, true statement. So in only 1+26/2=14 of them will this statement be made. In 7 of those, there are two boys. The answer is 1/2. NOTE: this way, each possible statement is made with the same probability. Your way, each is made a different number of times, with "Tuesday Boy" most often. Why?


@JeffJo in order to apply the Bayesian approach, one needs a well defined probability for the statements. If that is the case, such as in examples 1 and 2, then you can compute the posterior probability. A problem with the puzzle is that it doesn't provide a good way to know the likelihood function, but the answer here assumes different examples to show how these assumptions can change the solution.

This answer uses the assumption that the probability statement "One is a  who was born on a ." is chosen beforehand, and the information is only a binary true or false.

And since the problem statement does not indicate, in any way, that it was chosen beforehand? You can't make that assumption. It's like assuming, in the Monty Hall Problem, that Monty chose beforehand to open door #3 if he could. Which makes switching have no benefit. In fact, they are variations of the same problem. Martin Gardner actually posed the Three Prisoners Problem - the MHP's predecessor - to explain exactly what I am trying to explain about his Two Child Problem.

@JeffJo Indeed, the puzzle can technically not be solved because that missing information about the likelihood function. Without likelihood function you can not apply Bayes' rule. However, the question is about the intuition behind one of the particular assumptions and how it can matter that this assumption changes the solution. I explain what assumptions would be underlying that particular solution and how they change the solution relative to another assumption.

It can be solved, based on the information you have. And making that assumption is not valid. Making it differently for two kinds of information is worse.

@JeffJo no it can not be solved. Your 1/2 answer is invalid as well. You need a likelihood function and without it you can not solve it. But any likelihood function makes assumptions. The fact that my assumptions makes the answer different is a proof that assumptions are necessary (because not making those assumptions is just as well an assumption).

It can be solved, based on the Principle of Indifference. "In the absence of any relevant evidence, agents should distribute their credence (or "degrees of belief") equally among all the possible outcomes under consideration."

@JeffJo the prior probability for the same gender is indeed 1/2 and remains the same if the information from the statement is not linked to any likelihood (no need for a principle of indifference although it does explain is more intuitively), but then you assume that this lack of likelihood is the case.

If it had said the first child is a boy and asked what is the probability that the other one is a boy, it would be $1/2.$
If it had said the second child is a boy and asked what is the probability that the other one is a boy, it would be $1/2.$
But it doesn't say which one is a boy.
In the first sentence above, you have two possibilities:
(boy, girl), $\quad$ (boy, boy)
In the second sentence above, you have two possibilities:
(boy, boy), $\quad$ (girl, boy)
In the third sentence above you have three possibilities:
(boy, boy), $\quad$ (boy, girl), $\quad$ (girl, boy)
The probability that both are boys is $1/3.$

If he had two boys, a 1/4 chance, he could only say that one was a boy. If he had a boy and a girl, a 1/2 chance, he could have said either that one was a boy, or one was a girl. The fact that he chose one of these does not mean it was a requirement to choose that statement. So that 1/2 chance reduces to a 1/4 chance where he has a boy and a girl, and say that one is a boy. The chances he has two boys are now 50%.

This interpretation of the question has been amply discussed here on CV: see this site search.

Sextus is partially right. Where he goes wrong is the information he adds about there being at least one boy, but then declines to add the same way about Tuesday.
These problems are variations on the Bertrand Box Paradox. But the paradox was not the problem, as the word is used today, it was the contradiction that could arise if you add information without justification. The basic Two Child Problem is simply the Bertrand Box Problem with four boxes instead of three. Here is the paradox:

Mr. Smith says "I have two children, and at least one of them is a boy."
Mr. Jones says "I have two children, and at least one of them is a girl."
Mr. Bertrand says "I have two children, and I have written the gender of at least one inside this sealed envelope."

In each scenario, what is the probability that the two children share that gender?
The answers to Q1 and Q2 must be the same; that is, A1=A2. The contradiction comes from Q3. If we were to open the envelope, the question would reduce to either Q1 or Q2, and have the same answer. But that means we don't have to see what is in it - the answer is the same regardless of what is written, so A1=A2=A3.
But we have no information about gender in Q3, so A3=1/2. That means A1=A2=1/2 as well.
The reason A1=A2=1/3 is wrong, is because it assumes that Mr. Smith would always tell us about a boy even if he also has a daughter, and that Mr. Jones would always tell us about a girl even if he also has a son. Why can't Mr. Smith tell us about a daughter, or Mr. Smith tell us about a son? That's the added information.
Sextus adds this information when "decides to say boy" because "boy" is what is stated in the problem, but chooses the day by a flip of a coin even though "Tuesday" was similarly stated.
Here's the resolution of all these paradoxes: Anytime more than one statement of a similar fact could be made, and we do not know how one is chosen, we can only assume it is equally likely that any of them could be given. This is called the Principle of Indifference, and it is why we say a coin flip has a 1/2 chance to be Heads or Tails, or a die roll has a 1/6 chance to be any of {1,2,3,4,5,6}.
Using this in all of these variations says there is a 1/2 chance of matching genders, and there is no intuition failure since irrelevant information does not change the answer.

I'm sorry, but this is not the Principle of Indifference--it only seems like it.  The actual principle requires that there be some basis, usually in physical symmetry, to justify the equiprobability conclusion.  Although it might apply to coins and dice, it does not apply to arbitrary assertions.

In my answer I made indeed assumptions, but it is not to say that it is the answer. It is to explain the intuition how this additional information about the day can change the posterior probability and how the solution depends on assumptions.(Aside from that, the nature between the day and the gender is different. The information that at least one is a boy, however that has been decided to make that statement, does certainly exclude the probability of two girls. The information about the day is seemingly not important)

It is the PoI. All it requires is that there be no reason to favor one result over the other. Literally, "[PoI] states that in the absence of any relevant evidence, agents should distribute their credence equally among all the possible outcomes under consideration." And the reason for a change in the posterior probabilities is if we have relevant information that makes one of the possible outcomes more likely. "Two Boys" becomes more likely if we require certain information that includes "boy," because a two-boy family is more likely to have at least one than a one-boy family.

@JeffJo Can you cite your sources for this?
